# how to get the facebook id on a apprequests using the version 2.1?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am sending an app request using the version 2.1, I realized I get some request id at the response object, checked this issue seems like it is kinda common, still, everybody talk about the version 2.0 and about enable the *" request 2.0 efficient"* , however, I dont know if is because this is a new api and so on, and maybe facebook dropped that option, I couldnt find such option at the options (if someone can tell me where it was, I checked 10 times and I couldnt find it).

So, basically, I was wondering, if i get for response an object with **request id** and **response.to** -> many ids, is there a way to take those ids and get the user id whom i sent it?

Answer (score 0):

Unless a request is deleted, you will continue to retrieve any and all app requests that have been sent.  It's good practice to delete old requests so that only the newest is returned.  The 'to' field when reading /apprequests will always be the ID (now app-scoped in 2.0) of the user the request was sent to.